# Rust Rayon collect Options into Vector

Tags: rust, option-type, rayon

I am trying to use *rayon* `par_iter` with `map` (and `enumerate`).
However, the closure returns an Option.
Is there a way to collect the Some value of that option while filtering out Nones?
What I do currently is

```rust
let par_iter = seqs.into_par_iter().enumerate().map(|(i, d)| -> Option<(String, usize)> {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let is_ok = somefunc(d);
    if is_ok {
        return Some((d, i))
    } else {
        return None
    }
});

let res = par_iter.collect::<Vec<Option<(String, usize)>>>();

let mut output: Vec<(String, usize)> = Vec::new();
for opt in res {
    if let Some(d) = opt {
        output.push(d);
    }
}
```

where `seqs` is `Vec<String>`.
Is there a less verbose or more typical way of doing this?

Comment: Note that if you want to use `thread_rng()` in rayon task, it's better to use [`map_init()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.map_init), to avoid the cost of accessing the TLS each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

```rust
let res = seqs
    .into_par_iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(i, d)| -> Option<(String, usize)> {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        let is_ok = somefunc(d);
        if is_ok {
            return Some((d, i));
        } else {
            return None;
        }
    })
    .filter_map(std::convert::identity)
    .collect::<Vec<(String, usize)>>();
```

Or:

```rust
let res = seqs
    .into_par_iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(i, d)| -> Option<(String, usize)> {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        let is_ok = somefunc(d);
        if is_ok {
            return Some((d, i));
        } else {
            return None;
        }
    })
    .flatten()
    .collect::<Vec<(String, usize)>>();
```

From benchmarking using `criterion`, the `filter_map()` version is 10x faster, so you should probably use it.

Comment: Is there a reason to do `.map(…).filter_map(identity)` instead of just `.filter_map(…)`?

Comment: @cafce25 Not really, except if you use `map_init()`.